# bash script, list all the files over a specific size

Tags: bash, shell-script

so I have a line of code like this:

```
result=`find . -type f -size -1000c -print0 | xargs -0 ls -Sh | head`

for i in $result; do
    item=`wc -c $i`
    echo $item1 
done
```

this will print out all the files in the current fold that are at most 1000bytes, it has the format like:

size_of the file   ./name_of_the_file

but i want to get rid of the "./" symbol, so i try to use "cut"

i want to do something like:

```
for i in $result; do
    item=`wc -c $i`
    item1=`cut -f 1 $item`    // this gives me the size 
    item2=`cut -c 7- $item`   // this gives me all the character after ./ 
    echo item1, item2         // now make it print 
done
```

but i'm getting error like:

**`cut: 639: No such file or directory`**

can anyone please give me a hint on this? I appreciate it.

Comment: Never store file lists in a variable, and never ever parse `ls`.  And use `$()` instead of backticks to capture the output. Also, you are not giving `cut` a file or pipe to process. You are giving it an argument `$item` which is just a string, and apparently not a valid filename. You would need either `echo "$item" | cut -f 1` or `cut -f 1 <<<"$item"`. However, `cut` is also tricky about the delimiters. See answers below for a proper solution.

Comment: Also, wouldn't you need `+1000c` instead of minus to get files larger than the limit?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your system's support for POSIX, I believe this will give you the same result you are trying to achieve:

```
    find . -type f -size -1000c -printf '%P %s Bytes\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Synopsis of [`cut(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut):

```
cut OPTION... [FILE]...
```

It's expecting its last argument to be a file (or list of files). What you're doing is supplying `$item` as the last argument. It seems that `$item` is 639 which would explain the error message: you're passing 639 in a place where `cut` is expecting a file name argument. You need to replace `$item` in those `cut` calls with `$i`.

I think the best way to extract the file name (minus `./`) would be to use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) instead of relying on a fixed number of characters to be there every time:

```
item2="${i#*./}"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ls -l | awk '$5 <= 1000{print $5, $9}'
```

Comment: What happens when the filenames have spaces, or newlines in them?

Comment: @Anthon , very good question, this line can't handle the case you mentioned, although spaces and newlines are not recommend to be part of file names, they still should be taken good care of.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -size -1000c -printf "%s %f\n"
```

`%s`  prints File's size in bytes.
`%f`  prints File's name with any leading directories removed (only the last element).